# Validar uno o varios checkboxes de una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas amig@s eran para ver si me podrían ayudar para resolver un ejercicio que es el siguiente:

**Crear un documento PHP que permita al usuario comprobar el precio de varios
productos. El usuario, lo primero que verá será un listado con todos los
productos que hay en la base de datos. Al lado de cada producto habrá un
checkbox para que el usuario pueda seleccionar más de un producto a la vez.
Por medio de sentencias preparadas, mostrar al usuario el precio de todos los
productos seleccionados.
NOTA: la lista de productos también debe generarse con PHP**

He hecho el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "venta");
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
    $codigos=array();

    $sentencia = "select cod,descripcion from producto";
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);
    $consulta->bind_result($codigo,$descripcion);
    $consulta->execute();

    echo "<table border>";
    echo "<tr><td>Descripcion</td><td>Checkbox</td></tr>";
    while ($consulta->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr><td>$descripcion</td><td><form action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='codigos' value='$codigo'></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
        if (isset($_POST["codigos"])) {
            
            echo $codigo;
            
        }else{

        }
    }
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

El problema es que cuando hago el echo del producto que selecciono no me sale su código.
**Esta seria la base de datos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y esto seria lo que me muestra por pantalla:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que supongo que será el último codigo de la BD, he intentado meter la name del checkbox en un array pero tampoco me ha salido. Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Pon los códigos en un arreglo, en el input: `name='codigos[]'`. Para luego obtenerlos  del arreglo `$_POST['codigos']`.

Comment: No funciona eso que dices!

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con tu intento, para que te digamos que haces mal.